# two left outer joins query ambiguous column name

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, join, left-join, outer-join

I am making a rails 4 app for a 'question and answer' forum. I have a model Micropost. I have a model QuestionAnswer which connects different microposts as questions and answers:

```
Class Micropost < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many question_answers, foreign_key: "question_id"
  has_many answers, through: :question_answers
  has_one :reverse_question_answer, foreign_key: "answer_id", class_name: "QuestionAnswer"
  has_one :question, through: :reverse_question_answer
end

Class QuestionAnswer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :question, class_name: "Micropost"
  belongs_to :answer,   class_name: "Micropost"
end
```

Now I want to do a database query. I want to use two LEFT OUTER JOINs to create a joint table with all questions and answers:

```
Micropost.
  joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN question_answers ON question_answers.question_id = microposts.id').
  joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN microposts ON microposts.id = question_answers.answer_id')
```

I receive the error message

```
SQLite3::SQLException: ambiguous column name: microposts.id SELECT "microposts".* FROM "microposts" LEFT OUTER JOIN question_answers ON question_answers.question_id = microposts.id LEFT OUTER JOIN microposts ON microposts.id = question_answers.answer_id ORDER BY created_at DESC
```

I replaced micropost with answers in the second joins command above, but it complains there is no such table. How can I do two joins? -Thanks.

Comment: Shouldn't you just stick with one JOIN, but make it a FULL OUTER JOIN? Like: `FULL OUTER JOIN question_answers ON question_answers.question_id = microposts.id`

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am using SQLite3 which can't do FULL OUTER JOIN. Also, I need two joins because I want to go from microposts (as questions) to question_answers to microposts (as answers).

Comment: I see, can you try the following: `Micropost.
  joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN question_answers a ON a.question_id = microposts.id').
  joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN microposts m ON m.id = a.answer_id')`

Comment: Yes, it works. Thank you very much... Just to make sure I understand what you did: in your notation '...JOIN question_answers a ON...' the 'a' there stands for one row of 'question_answers' table? right? You again use the same row in the 2nd JOIN command. right? Can you suggest a reference/blog/etc that for more information about this?

Comment: It is known as an alias, this is so that you can reference the same table multiple times and the server will know which one you mean. Also useful for shortening table names in the select statement or giving them more appropriate names if need be. http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp

Comment: @PrzemyslawKruglej Please post your comment as an answer so that the OP can close this question. May also be worth including the link to aliasing tables. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to use the following piece of code:

```
Micropost.
  joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN question_answers a ON a.question_id = microposts.id').
  joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN microposts m ON m.id = a.answer_id')
```

As per your question about aliases, the `a` alias stands for the whole `question_answers` table. In this particular example, it's just for convenience. However, the `m` alias, used for `microposts`, is not.

Here we define that `m` is an alias for `microposts` table to signal that it's a different table than the one you are joining before using `a.question_id = microposts.id` (here the microposts is the first 'instance' of `microposts` table, and in the next JOIN you define another instance to which you give an `m` alias).

Not sure if I explained this clearly, look here:

```
SELECT e.name, mgr.name
  FROM employees e
    JOIN employees mgr ON (e.manager_id = mgr.id)
;
```

Here we have again two instances of employees table - we join rows from both tables to get employee's name and his manager's name. Aliases are required here because otherwise it would be unclear which column is taken from which table.

If you would like to learn more about JOIN, you can read:

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Or (there are further links about JOINs, nicely shown and explained, hope it will be useful to you):

[What is the difference between "INNER JOIN" and "OUTER JOIN"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549/difference-between-inner-and-outer-join)